# SQL Case Statement in set; Does it always fire?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I was wondering if in the following statement:

```
  UPDATE u 
  SET u.isactive = 
        (
        CASE WHEN e.LVStatus<>'B' AND u.IsActive=1 AND u.AutoUpdate=1 THEN 
              0
        WHEN e.LVStatus='B' AND u.IsActive=0 AND u.AutoUpdate=1 THEN 
              1 END
         ),
      u.UpdatedB y= 0 
  FROM tbl_e e                                        
       INNER JOIN tbl_Users u ON e.id=u.id
```

If the conditions in the case statement are not met, for example u.IsActive=1 and e.LVStatus='B', will the query still set u.UpdatedBy=0? I was hoping if the conditions in the case statement are not met then do nothing, perhaps if I want that behavior I need to just have to separate update statements with different where clauses. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your query sets `u.UpdatedBy` to zero unconditionally, the answer is yes, the value of `u.UpdatedBy` will be set regardless of the outcome of the `CASE` expression through which `u.isactive` is set.

To overcome this, you could add a separate `CASE` expression for the `u.UpdatedBy` field, and use the current value when the conditions of the other `CASE` statement are not met:

```
UPDATE u 
SET u.isactive = CASE
        WHEN e.LVStatus<>'B' AND u.IsActive=1 AND u.AutoUpdate=1 THEN 0
        WHEN e.LVStatus='B' AND u.IsActive=0 AND u.AutoUpdate=1 THEN 1
        ELSE u.isactive
    END
,   u.UpdatedBy= CASE
        WHEN (e.LVStatus<>'B' AND u.IsActive=1 AND u.AutoUpdate=1) OR
             (e.LVStatus='B' AND u.IsActive=0 AND u.AutoUpdate=1)
        THEN 0
        ELSE u.UpdatedBy
    END 
FROM tbl_e e                                        
     INNER JOIN tbl_Users u ON e.id=u.id
```

Alternatively, you could move that condition into the `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
UPDATE u 
SET u.isactive = CASE
        WHEN e.LVStatus<>'B' AND u.IsActive=1 AND u.AutoUpdate=1 THEN 0
        WHEN e.LVStatus='B' AND u.IsActive=0 AND u.AutoUpdate=1 THEN 1
        -- No ELSE is needed, because WHERE filters out all other cases
    END
,   u.UpdatedBy=0
FROM tbl_e e
INNER JOIN tbl_Users u ON e.id=u.id
WHERE (e.LVStatus<>'B' AND u.IsActive=1 AND u.AutoUpdate=1) OR
      (e.LVStatus='B' AND u.IsActive=0 AND u.AutoUpdate=1)
```

Comment: The alternative is exactly what I would like to do, though I could update to the same values, the alternative solution is a much cleaner approach for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both set conditions will always work.  A `CASE` expression without an `ELSE` clause has an implicit `ELSE NULL`.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

If `u.isactive` has a `NOT NULL` constraint, you'll get a constraint violation and nothing will be updated by the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `SET u.isactive = (CASE... ELSE u.isactive end)`.

That way, if your criteria in the case statment aren't met, just leave it as the existing value.  You could probably get away with no else statement, but I am never comfortable with that.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to add an `else` clause and return the column's original value:

```
UPDATE u 
  SET u.isactive=(CASE WHEN e.LVStatus<>'B' AND u.IsActive=1 AND u.AutoUpdate=1 THEN 0
                       WHEN e.LVStatus='B' AND u.IsActive=0 AND u.AutoUpdate=1 THEN 1 
                       ELSE u.isactive END),
      u.UpdatedBy=0 
  FROM tbl_e e                                        
       INNER JOIN tbl_Users u ON e.id=u.id
```